# Edges in a graph containing connected components

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph having $k$ connected components, each of which is a tree. If $G$ has $n$ vertices, how many edges does it have?

I want to use the formula $2|E| =  \sum_{v \in G}^{}deg(w)$, but I am not sure what to put for $deg(w)$. Any hints?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the relationship between the number of vertices and the number of edges in a tree?

Comment: Edges = vertices - 1?

Comment: Yes. So in each component you have one more vertex than you have edges. And there are $k$ components, so in the graph as a whole what happens?

Comment: I got $(n-1)*k  $, but we also have to compute edges between components, right?

Comment: By definition there are no edges between components. But $k(n-1)$ isn’t right anyway. Suppose that the components are $T_1,T_2,\ldots,T_k$, and that there are $n_1$ vertices in $T_1$, $n_2$ vertices in $T_2$, and so on. How many edges are there in $T_1$? In $T_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$? Now use the fact that $n_1+\ldots+n_k=n$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!